# The store components are repeated in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have have defined three separate redux slices namely user, profile, and general which are defined as:

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  username: null,
  token: null
}

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'user',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    login: (state, action) => {
      state.username = action.payload.username
      state.token = action.payload.token
    },
    logout: (state) => {
      state.username = null
      state.token = null
    },
  },
})

export const { login, logout } = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  name: null,
  family: null,
  phoneNumber: null
}

export const profileSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'profile',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setProfile: (state, action) => {
      state.name = action.payload.name
      state.family = action.payload.family
      state.phoneNumber = action.payload.phoneNumber
    },
    deleteProfile: (state) => {
      state.name = null
      state.family = null
      state.phoneNumber = null
    },
  },
})

export const { setProfile, deleteProfile } = profileSlice.actions

export default profileSlice.reducer
```

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const initialState = {
  isPreparing: false,
  isLogedIn: false,
}

export const generalSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'general',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setIsPreparing: (state, action) => {
      state.isPreparing = action.payload.isPreparing
    },
    setIsLogedIn: (state, action) => {
      state.isLogedIn = action.payload.isLogedIn
    },

  },
})

export const { setIsPreparing, setIsLogedIn } = generalSlice.actions

export default generalSlice.reducer
```

the store is defined as:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from './userSlice'
import profileReducer from './profileSlice'
import generalReducer from './generalSlice';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const persistedUserReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, userReducer)
const persistedProfileReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, profileReducer)
const persistedGeneralReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, generalReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user: persistedUserReducer,
    profile: persistedProfileReducer,
    general: persistedGeneralReducer,
  },
  middleware: [thunk],
})

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```

I'm using the the following examples to update the values of the store:

```
dispatch(login({ username: username, token: response.data.key }))
dispatch(setIsLogedIn({ isLogedIn: true }))
dispatch(setIsPreparing({ isPreparing: true }))
```

After running the dispatch statements, each component constitutes a copy of all the variables:
[image]

Am I doing wrong? what is my mistake? would you please help me to find the problem?

Comment: Can you show how you've used `combineReducers`?

Comment: the combineReducers is included in the revised question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap all your reducers in `combineReducers`:

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import userReducer from './userSlice'
import profileReducer from './profileSlice'
import generalReducer from './generalSlice';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import { persistReducer, persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
 user: userReducer,
 profile: profileReducer,
 general: generalReducer 
})

const persistedReducer = persistReducer({...persistConfig}, rootReducer)

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: [thunk],
})

export const persistor = persistStore(store)
```